# Eclipse does not show error icon in package explorer if xml file is not well formed

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, package-explorer

Eclipse doesn't show the error icon in the package explorer for xml files that are not well-formed/not valid (after I have saved the file). Is this an intended behaviour? Can I customize that? I wasn't able to find anything on the preferences. I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2.

[image]

Update: I need to perform "Validate" on the file from context. After this validation has finished, the error icon is also shown in the package explorer. This seems unintuitive.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html). Apparently, the xml validation process has to be triggered manually from context menu and is not part of the project build process. To change this, open the project settings, navigate to `Validation` and check `Add Validation Builder to project`. Once you check it, it will not be shown anymore. Instead, it is part of the build process and can be enabled/disabled as `Validation` in the project settings in the `Builder` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check that XML Validation is enebled.
Right click on project Properties->Validation->XML Syntax
Or try 
Window->Preferences->Xml->Xml Files->Validation

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I can't find any appropriate settings for this. I need to perform a "Validate" from the context menu. Then the error icon is shown as well in the package explorer.